# Android integration Amazon S3 and Identity Pool

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know that Amazon provides plenty of information on this topic, however there is so much that I cannot find my way around it. I will defenetily continue searching, and if I find the answer on my own question I will post it here. But maybe someone can give me a push in the right direction.

I am developing an android app, and what that:

1. users can store / retrieve a zip file from Amazon S3
2. The user can only access its own zip file on Amazon S3

For this I was thinking of:

1. I will create an Amazon Cognito Identity pool
2. The user can register/sign in, using a GUI in my app
3. The Amazon IAM policy of this Identity pool, is set in such a way that the users can only read/write the Amazon S3 bucket linked to my app, and can only read/write a file beginning with their username

The first and third part I have done, basically the non-android part. Now I need to figure out on how to integrate this in my app.

1. How to build a GUI in which passwords and other private information remain safe, or are communicated safely to Amazon Cognito
2. How to set up a TransferUtility (or something alike) to transfer the data from the divice to the Amazon S3 bucket and back

Can someone point me into the right direction? Or have a code example which I can use to build mine from?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Mobile Hub helps setup the Cognito, IAM, and S3 portions of your project.

The AWS Mobile SDK has the GUI that can help sign in users in their aws-android-sdk-auth-ui package.

Details for setting up that GUI can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile-hub/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html)

Details for using S3 with Transfer Utility can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile-hub/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-data-storage.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. even after 1,5 day of googling and working my way through the Amazon help I did not end up on these two. Many thanks!